# NodeJS SQLite3 Database is locked

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I get the error 'SQLite_BUSY: database is locked' quite a few times.
It is not because I have opened the database with another program. I think it is because I try to add too many rows after each other into the database. This makes the application crash multiple times a day.

I'm not very known with databases and sqlite, so probably there is a much better way of doing this. But for me this seems ok(ish).

So let me explain a little bit. I have this JSON file of ±1000-1500 items and I want to check every item of that row. I try to get the item from the database, if that doesn't happen I know it has not been here before; I add it to the database, and send a message in a Discord Channel. If the item has already been here before (so it has been found in the database), nothing will happen. Between 5-50 items will be added each time the function is called.

I found out that not closing the database (see the // below) made it less frequent to happen. So I decided not to close it. Probably not a good way of handling things, but this seems to work better. But every now and then 'SQLITE_BUSY: database is locked' will occur.

So my question is: How can I improve this so 'database is locked' will not occur. Are there things I should do differently, or is there a complete other method what will work much better?

```
function sendFiltered(jsonObjects, channel_id){

  if(jsonObjects != null){
    const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('./database.db', (err) => {
      if(err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
      }
    });

    jsonObjects.forEach((item) => {
      db.serialize(function() {
        db.get("SELECT * FROM items WHERE encounterId = ?", [item.encounter_id], (err, row) => {
          if (err) {
            return console.error(err.message);
          }

          if(row == undefined){
            request({
                url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + item.lat + "," + item.lon + "&key=KEY",
                json: true
            }, function (error, response, body) {

                let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                  .setTitle(item.name + ' ' + item.id)
                  .setThumbnail("attachment://" + getThumb(item.id) + ".png");

                const files = [{
                  attachment: 'img/items/' + getThumb(item.id) + '.png',
                  name: getThumb(item.id) + '.png'
                }];

                db.run("INSERT INTO items (encounterId) VALUES (?)", [item.encounter_id]);
                client.channels.get(channel_id).send(item.name + ' ' + 'level ' + item.level, {embed, files});

            });

          } else {
            console.log('Already send in channel');
          }

        });
      });
    });

    // db.close((err) => {
    //   if(err) {
    //     return console.error(err.message);
    //   }
    // });

  }
}
```

I removed some unnecessary code (Discord RichEmbed) to make it more readable.

Comment: Have you tried using the WAL journal mode?

Comment: Can you explain a bit about that? I've seen that a couple of times but I didn't quite understand it

Comment: [WAL Mode](https://sqlite.org/wal.html) is a particular file storage mode. The point that sticks out to me is that it "provides more concurrency as readers do not block writers and a writer does not block readers".

Comment: I'm still getting 
`events.js:193 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event Error: SQLITE_BUSY: database is locked`

It happened after the 33th item that wasn't already in the database.

I removed `db.serialize` and used `dbwildpokemon.run( 'PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;' );` before the `forEach`. But it seems it still fails.
Do you have any other thoughts?